# Objective-C: Text on my UILabel is not wrapping properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, nsstring, uilabel

I'm having a little trouble with a uilabel that should display 1 of 5 random strings. Sometimes the entire string displays with no problem, but more often than not, some of the text is cut off. Here's what I currently have:

```
// These are the 5 NSStrings which are placed in an array.
NSString *badOne = @"Bad? Your bill is nothing. I would consider that good service. SMDH.";
NSString *badTwo = @"You left out the amount dude.";
NSString *badThree = @"I can't tell you what the tip should be, if you don't tell me how much you dropped.";
NSString *badFour = @"Forgetting something?";
NSString *badFive = @"The tip should be over 9000... /n kidding.";

NSArray *badComments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:badOne, badTwo, badThree, badFour, badFive, nil];

// A random string is selected and assigned to badJoke.    
int rand = arc4random()%5;

NSString *badJoke = [badComments objectAtIndex:rand];

// Here's the problematic code:    
[_mainLabel setText:(badJoke)];
[_mainLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 295, 200, 80)];
_mainLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
_mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

[_amountTextField resignFirstResponder];

// This is a separate label, completely unrelated.    
[_tipAmount setText:@""];
```

So for example, one of the times it might show "Bad? Your bill is no".
I've also tried without the setFrame line and no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is happening when you increase the UILabel frame? Is it changing?

Comment: will be helpful if you could post some screenshots of the result you got

Answer (score 0):

Ideal solution is to calculate the exact frame needed to display the text inside the lable...

```
NSString *badJoke = [badComments objectAtIndex:rand];

CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(200, CGFLOAT_MAX);//you can give any max width which you feel that suits you...

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];/Give your font size

CGSize size = [badJoke sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
//size.height will get you the total height of the lable to be created.

_mainLable=[[UILable alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 295, size.width, size.height)];
//if you haven't initialized.Or else you can use the same as you were using..[_mainLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 295, size.width, size.height)];

_mainLabel.text= badJoke;

_mainLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

_mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

I am not sure with the syntax,because i wrote the code on my notepad.Hope it works for you.Happy coding :)